# How do you reuse the same button over and over, but with a different id?

Tags: android, layout, android-button

I've tried using the include/merge tools in the android studio docs, but all I can mess with is the "look" (layout parameters) of the buttons. (i.e. the location, font size, color)

What I'd like to do is load hundreds of layouts in a certain order, controlled via buttons.

For example:
Button_1 on Screen_1 takes you to Screen_2.
Screen_2 has Button_1 too, but re-packaged with a new way for it to load up the Screen_3 layout.

Does Android Studio allow you to reuse the same button with different functionality, or are we stuck with overwriting the visuals only?

There's a small voice in the back of my head telling me that doing it this way will make my app too big. If there's a better way to get this same effect without needing to re-draw a new layout each time.

Comment: Well, an `id` should be used to uniquely identify, and doesn't that defeat the purpose?

Comment: hey David! You're pretty much right on, I'm just trying to avoid using multiple layouts that perform similar functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Android Studio allow you to reuse the same button with different
> functionality, or are we stuck with overwriting the visuals only?

To reuse the same Button in different Screens but also reuse some button functionalities can be achieved by using a custom Button View.

Let's say you want to reuse a specific MaterialButton.

1.Create a custom button eg: `MyReuseButton` which is a subclass of `MaterialButton` like below:

```
public class MyReuseButton extends MaterialButton {

    public MyReuseButton(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyReuseButton(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyReuseButton(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        //these are the default Button attributes
        setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.darker_gray));
        setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.black));
        setText("My Button Default Text");
    }

    public void setButtonLogicForScreen1(){
       //do your button functionalities for Screen1 (which is also reused in case some other screen needs the same functionalities)
    }

    public void setButtonLogicForScreen2(){
       //do your button functionalities for Screen2 (which is also reused in case some other screen needs the same functionalities)
    }
}
```

2.You can reuse this button in every screen you want using a different ID like below:

```
<com.my.packagename.MyReuseButton
   android:id="@+id/myButtonId1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

3.And of course you can reuse some Button functionalities eg: for Screen 1 like:

```
 MyReuseButton myReuseButton = findViewById(R.id.myButtonId1);
 myReuseButton.setButtonLogicForScreen1(); //of course this can be reused over other screens as well
```

or in Screen 2:

```
MyReuseButton myReuseButton = findViewById(R.id.myButtonId2);
myReuseButton.setButtonLogicForScreen2(); //of course this can be reused over other screens as well
```

Comment: ohh, that makes sense. That's a great idea! Thank you Mario!!!!! I'd upvote but my rep isn't high enough. I'll try this out this weekend and see where it gets me : D

Comment: Just got finished. This actually was just what I needed. Thanks again for helping a guy out

Comment: You are welcome @Chris. Glad to help. You can accept my answer if it solved your problem. Check the following link to see how to accept an answer on StackOverflow: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work